# How do I fetch-mock an accurate server error?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, fetch-mock

The issue:

fetchmock

```js
fetchMock.get('glob:https://*/server-api-uri', () => {
  throw { example: 'error' }
})
```

Source JS file:

```js
exampleServerCall().catch(error => {
  console.log(error) // error = "[ object object ]" :(
})
```

So my catch statements are returning with a useless `"[ object object ]"` string when what I really want is access to the full mocked server error.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the MDN docs for throw, I found [documentation for how to throw a custom object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw#throw_an_object) in a throw handler.

You need to do it by creating a custom class object.

fetchmock

```js
class CustomError {
    example = 'error'
}

fetchMock.get('glob:https://*/server-api-uri', () => {
  throw new CustomError()
})
```

source JS file:

```js
exampleServerCall().catch(error => {
  console.log(error) // error = { example: 'error' } :D
})
```